# Using a PHP if statement to change a link dynamically

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, paypal

I am trying to create a form using the post method with a php script. Everything works except where it lets users choose between multiple packages.
On the confirmation page, there is a Pay Now button that I want to lead to a different Paypal payment page based on which package they choose on the form (the confirmation page is combined into the php script file). The problem is when I create the If statements in the script to say if `$variable = "This"` then `$pay_link = this`, `a href="<?php echo($pay_link); ?>"` it changes the `$variable` to `"This"` instead of just checking if it `= "This"`.

Is there any way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: There should be no problem doing this. It's not clear from your question why you're having trouble. You should post some code.

Comment: For example, trying to achieve this: if ($escaped_Plan = "Basic Plan")
 $pay_url="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=RemovedIDforSecurityReasons";

For some reason that changes $escaped_Plan to "Basic Plan" instead of just checking if $escaped_Plan = "Basic Plan".

Comment: Please post _actual code_, not a description of the code. You probably have a syntax error, as in samanime's answer, but we can't tell for sure without seeing what you wrote.

Comment: For security purposes, I unfortunately cannot post the actual full code (PCI Compliance, etc). However, I can say that this is a word for word quote of the code, and samanime's answer worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to do this:

```
if ($variable = "This")
```

A single equal is the "assignment" operator, so you are basically saying:

```
Assign "This" to $variable, then if $variable is a non-fasle-y value, do something.
```

What you want is ==, which is the "boolean comparison" operator

```
if ($variable == "This")
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: That worked. And you were exactly right on what I am trying to do and what I want.

Comment: If this was the answer, please mark it as such so people in the future who find this page via Google will know.